# By default, where does Spring Boot expect views to be stored?

Tags: maven, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm experimenting on re-writing my configuration-heavy, vanilla Spring MVC project using Spring Boot. I started a brand new Spring Boot project in IntelliJ using the Spring Boot Initiaizer and I'm going the route of minimal Java-based configuration. Lots of tutorials point out that the default main class generated is sufficient and that `@SpringBootApplication` has everything included. I got a sample REST Controller to work and return a serialized object as JSON, but it appears getting a view to show is proving difficult. My structure is as follows, with everything default other than the webapps directory which I created.

```
src
`-main
   `-java
   `-resources
     `-static
     `-templates
   `-webapp
     `-WEB-INF
        `-home.jsp
```

The controller is plain simple.

```
@Controller
public class ViewMaster {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Without any configuration, I'd like to know where Spring Boot expects the views to be stored and with what extension (html?). I've also tried to include the following in `application.properties` but I still get a 404 error. Moving the WEB-INF directory or just the html file around in resources didn't help either.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I've also tried including these dependencies in my pom.xml without any effect.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I must be missing something painfully obvious here so appreciate if someone can point that out!

Comment: Have you read this? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines

Comment: I don't see any `.jsp` files under your `/WEB-INF/` directory. I see only `home.html` file, is that a jsp file and a typo error in question?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. Did not know about the JSP limitations.

Comment: @SanjayRawat Yes that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Old, but this might still be relevant: Isn't the `WEB_INF` directory supposed to only hold _hidden_ views?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The Solution**

I found the answer via trial-and-error, which turned out rather annoying. I hope someone can correct me if this conclusion is wrong, but it appears that Spring Boot does not like the string `WEB-INF`. I renamed the `WEB-INF` directory to `view` and changed the `application.properties` to the following and the view loaded successfully.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**Additional Findings**

The objective of this exercise was to create a working example of a **minimal**, Java-based configuration so I continued minimalising the setup. I then found that lots of advice dished out on multiple SO threads and forums did not help. @JBNizet provided a link in his comment to the Spring Boot docs which lists a very salient point that no one has mentioned: **JSPs simply do not play well with Spring Boot as it has limitations depending on the embedded container chosen**. With that in mind, I decided to try replacing JSPs with ThymeLeaf templates.

My new working config removes the need for these:

- No need to add `application.properties`: `spring.mvc.view.prefix` + `spring.mvc.view.suffix`
- No need to change the packaging type from **jar** to **war**
- No need to modify main class
- No need to add pom.xml dependencies for

  - `org.springframework.boot / spring-boot-starter-tomcat`
  - `org.springframework.boot / tomcat-embed-jasper`
  - `javax.servlet / jstl`

So just the default Spring Boot template and 2 ThymeLeaf dependencies with the views named as `ViewName.html` placed in `src/main/resources/templates`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The ThymeLeaf part is the second part of this answer. The first paragraph answers the original question. Unless you can prove that somehow the WEB-INF configuration was working for you? I did a simple rename of the view directory and the configuration somehow worked. All the "solutions" you proposed did not work and you are being sore about it by marking my answer down when it is the only answer that has resolved the issue. You are being a very bad sport in this community.

Comment: um...... the my works for me i use spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp in application proeprties

Comment: In my opinion the best way today for useing spring in a web enviroment is use ThymeLeaf but if you askhelps for jsp I answare for jsp

Comment: I have just tried that and it does not work. I am using a completely empty structure so there should be no other factors. This is the error: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Mar 20 18:05:56 SGT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: ? it is impossible. repeate the step: empty project. do the my advice. create of course a controller for reatcive the url that you test and deploy it in a tomcat, i try with tomcat 8

Comment: if you want i post on my github the my poceven if is very similar to the offical guide:     https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

Comment: @tys The answer "Valerio Vaudi" posted works fine, I just created a spring-boot-jsp-demo project with all the config you mentioned in the the question and it is working fine.

Comment: I now suspect this has something to do with IntelliJ. Assume both of you are using eclipse/STS?

Comment: i found out my error was the way i was executing the app instead executing it on a server tomcat i was executing it as a spring boot app

Answer (score 8):

Without any configuration Spring Boot expects the views to be stored inside /webapp, the view page may be of any format depends on application.properties settings(like html or jsp) 
to set .jsp as view page at /views/ folder

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp //for .html change it to .html
```

and you have to use tomcat jaspher , if you don't include it the page will not be parsed instead it gets downloaded as a file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Answer (score 2):

If you found this article and you are returning

```
return "home.jsp";
```

instead of just "home". Then you must remove

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Otherwise remove .jsp from home and keep the suffix!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the JSP pages was well placed and the required configuration was set correctly in application.properties

After a long examination, I finally found that the problem was caused by the dependency "spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf" that should be removed from the pom.xml. Indeed, this dependency supports the XHML/HTML files in web application, whereas we are using JSP pages

Therefore, if we are using JSP pages in Spring MVC, any kind of the following dependency should be **removed**:

```
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

According to answer given by @Jasbin karki I tried and found placing your html or jsp files in main->webapp->views folder(you should create the webapp & views folders) and adding the following lines in application.properties file does the task.
Add the following in application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html //or .jsp- if its a jsp file
```

Comment: your answer isn't providing any additional insight into this issue. this question already has an accepted answer from 5 years+ ago and has had multiple other answers added so i'm not sure why you are adding another duplicate. if you are trying to clarify a point, please use comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first think that you have do, is insert the dependency in pour pom like below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

With this dependency you say at spring boot that the embedded tomcat dependency are provided and this have the effect that your spring app don't have the tomcat dependency inside the jar.

The second think that you have do, is change the pakaging proeprties in your pon from jar to war like below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
...
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    ....
</project>
```

The third and last think that you heve do is refactor the standard Application Boot startrer like below

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

for your configuration in application properties may be fine but I suggest you to put the your jsp under a specific folder and then refactor the your config for point to the new path, and not just under WEB-INF but this is just an advice.

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: All 3 steps did not help

Comment: it is very strange can you do more details about the your errors?

Comment: the error was a vanilla 404 not found. i've found the root cause and posted my own answer. feel free to test and critique!

Comment: Ok I readed your answare and this is true, spring boot expect the your view by deffault in templates. but in your question appear that you want conserv the your legacy structure whit jsp and an maven project style for webapp running on a standalone werver. If you are ready to migrate your legacy app written in jsp to a new web app with embedded web server ( for this reason you don't need to change from jar to war), don't use jsp in a standalone web server (for this reason you don't need th my other changing)

Comment: ok the my answare is not correct but in really the your question are not correct. If you say please help me to running this kind of structure I try to help you but if you can change the your application structure the case is totally different. Anyway I'm very happy for you that you found the problem

Answer (score -1):

tys, pls try to add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Reference : https://github.com/lenicliu/examples/tree/master/examples-spring-boot/examples-spring-boot-jsp

`spring.mvc.view.prefix` is a relative path of webapp folder, and u can put jsp files into it.

Comment: This was not required.

Answer (score -1):

### `application.properties`

Remove:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Add:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix= .html
```

### `pom.xml`

Remove jasper dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add thymeleaf dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Details: [Using thymeleaf instead of jsp](https://github.com/hovermind/springboot-webmvc/blob/master/README.md#thymeleaf-instead-of-jsp)

Answer (score -2):

```
<!-- Tomcat for JSP rendering -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Change Scope to "default" solved my problem

Comment: this is irrelevant to the question asked, which already has many established answers here.