# spring boot jsp application not configured

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I was trying to make a spring boot jsp application. So, I had gone to `http://start.spring.io/` and selected web module and application is download into local folder.

After importing project into eclipse, I made an entry into **application.properties** as

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Then I created one controller as

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hellopage() {
        return "ankit";
    }
}
```

Lastly, I added one jsp under WEB-INF/jsp folder as ankit.jsp

After starting the application, I hit the url `http://localhost:8080/hello` and I get response as **`Whitelabel Error Page`**

While I spend many hours to return jsp from spring-boot mvc with no success,

I tried to return the response from controller as **REST SERVICE**. So, I had made only few changes

1) Replace @Controller with @RestController

2) remove entry from appliation.properties

Then, I run main class and got the successful response on hitting the url `http://localhost:8080/hello`

**So, my question is why there is so much pain in configuring spring boot to return response into jsp page.**

EDIT:

Initially, my application is started with following class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But after few people suggestions, i changed it to following

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

        return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

However, result is same. After referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100212/by-default-where-does-spring-boot-expect-views-to-be-stored#answer-36112153), I had rename **WEB-INF** folder to **view**. On hitting the /hello url, my jsp is download into my local machine.

So, rendering the jsp from controller is again a mystery.

I need to either:

1. made a rest application instead of web application
2. switch to thymeleaf template engine instead of jsp
3. put more research into it jsp rendering

Thanks for your answers

Comment: how you initialize SpringBootApplication ?

Comment: Put an image of your project structure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100212/by-default-where-does-spring-boot-expect-views-to-be-stored
Try this solution

Comment: I think something wrong with your project structure. Can you please post image of your project structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Things you should check when using Spring boot with JSP :

- Make sure you have a subclass of SpringBootServletInitializer in you project. It should look like this :

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  ```

  public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  ```
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
  ```

  }
- Make sure to use a "war" packaging
- Make sure to declare the following provided dependency in your pom.xml : spring-boot-starter-tomcat

If it still doesn't work, try it with an external server instead of the embedded tomcat.

That said, Thymeleaf or Freemarker templates will be a lot easier to deal with. Thymeleaf is used by the Spring documentation so you might want to check that.

Comment: thanks for answer. i tried your suggestions but it didn't work for me. i will consider using Thymeleaf in future applications.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your `application.properties` is ok with

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Your `Controller` class is ok with

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hellopage() {
        return "ankit";
    }
}
```

Your main application is ok with

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have created folder `webapp` inside `main`. `WEB-INF` inside `webapp`. and `jsp` folder inside `WEB-INF`. And `ankit.jsp` inside  `jsp` folder. 
One more thing add these dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```