# Spring return String but must return html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
@RestController
public class ControllerCustomer {
    @RequestMapping("customer")
    public String customer(){
        return "customer";
    }
```

File customer.html in template folder

[image]

Comment: Please post your project structure.

Comment: Use `@Controller`. `@RestController` will return the response as is.

Comment: @RestController is the culprit. :)

Comment: Pa tison, You told me that you want to use jsp page, that's why I added new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jsp then create a folder

```
main -> 
      webapp -> 
        WEB-INF-> 
          views
```

Put your jsp page inside `views` folder. 
Now in your `application.properties` add these lines

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

Now in your `pom.xml` add these dependenct

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the Spring MVC?

Use Spring MVC InternalResourceViewResolver by adding this in spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"></property>
 </bean>
```

and only return "customer" in the controller

In your annotation-driven configuration the InternalResourceViewResolver should be set in the configuration class which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter like such:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}
```

These two lines will do all the magic.

```
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".html");
```

where it will set the customer to customer.html and your pages should be in /WEB-INF/pages/.

If you are using Spring boot add these two properties in application.properties,

```
  spring.mvc.view.prefix=/view/
  spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

and also add these two dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
<artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
<artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

views named as customer.html placed in src/main/resources/templates.

Follow this answer to complete understanding.
[By default, where does Spring Boot expect views to be stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100212/by-default-where-does-spring-boot-expect-views-to-be-stored)

Comment: Maybe You have example?

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter deprecated?