# Unable to resolve view in servlet with Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am running a spring MVC application using SpringBoot. The problem is that it seems like SpringBoot do not recognize my .jsp files, even though I have configured them in application.properties like:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

As I know so far, it might be a problem of .war and .jar files. I have tried all the methods found on the internet, but not success so far.

[UPDATED]
My project structure is:

```
├───.mvn
│   └───wrapper
│           maven-wrapper.jar
│           maven-wrapper.properties
│           MavenWrapperDownloader.java
│
├───main
│   └───webapp
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com
│   │   │       └───pages
│   │   │           ├───config
│   │   │           ├───controller
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           ├───dao
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           ├───licenta
│   │   │           │       LicentaApplication.java
│   │   │           │       MvcConfiguration.java
│   │   │           │       ServletInitializer.java
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           ├───model
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           ├───service
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           └───utils
│   │   ├───resources
│   │   │   │   application.properties
│   │   │   │   fisediscipline.sql
│   │   │   │   hibernate.cfg.xml
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   │   │       additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───static
│   │   │   └───templates
│   │   │
│   │   └───webapp
│   │       ├───META-INF
│   │       │       context.xml
│   │       │
│   │       ├───resources
│   │       │   ├───css
│   │       │   │
│   │       │   └───js
│   │       │     
│   │       │
│   │       └───WEB-INF
│   │           │   servlet-spring.xml
│   │           │
│   │           └───view
│   │               │   CompetentaProf.jsp
│   │               │   CompetentaProfFormular.jsp
│   │               │   CompetentaTrans.jsp
│   │               │   CompetentaTransFormular.jsp
│   │               │   Disciplina.jsp
│   │               │   DisciplinaFormular.jsp
│   │               │   DisciplinaVizualizare.jsp
│   │               │   login.jsp
│   │               │
│   │               └───base
│   │                       backgr.jpg
│   │                       meta.jsp
│   │                       navigation.jsp
│   │
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───com
│               └───pages
│                   └───licenta
│                           LicentaApplicationTests.java
│
└───target
    ├───classes
    │   │   application.properties
    │   │   fisediscipline.sql
    │   │   hibernate.cfg.xml
    │   │
```

So here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pages</groupId>
    <artifactId>licenta</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>licenta</name>
    <description>Aplicatie de Gesiune</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>-->
<!--        <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        <optional>true</optional>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>-->
<!--            &lt;!&ndash;<version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- For iText -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.pages.licenta.LicentaApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application.properies:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp


server.port=8083
server.port.http=8080
server.servlet.contextPath=/fisediscipline

#server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar

spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true   

#Proprietati legate de baza de date
spring.datasource.tomcat.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/fisediscipline
spring.datasource.tomcat.username=root
spring.datasource.tomcat.password=root

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/fisediscipline
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

### Setari Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true

#Proprietati Hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true

jwt.header=Authorization
jwt.secret=mySecret
jwt.expiration=604800
jwt.route.authentication.path=/login
jwt.route.authentication.refresh=/refresh

spring.security.basic.enabled=false
```

Spring Boot configuration class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration//(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.pages")
@EntityScan("com.pages.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.pages.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
public class LicentaApplication {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(LicentaApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LicentaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Additional class for View Resolver:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [By default, where does Spring Boot expect views to be stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100212/by-default-where-does-spring-boot-expect-views-to-be-stored)

Comment: YOur pages are in `/WEB-INF/pages` not in `/WEB-INF/view`. Also you are trying very hard to not use the Spring boot auto configuration, why?

Comment: @M.Deinum it was my mistake that I put the old project structure with the /WEB-INF/pages. I updated my question now so I have view. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @grog I have tried that already.

Comment: For starters remove your `MvcConfiguration` and `@EnableWebMvc` from your configuration. That disables the auto web configuration from Spring Boot.