# Spring Security gives and error while logging in through a modelpage of html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am using spring boot for my project and spring security with in memory h2 database while registration it goes well but when I send login request from a bootstrap mode to login then it throws exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'userid': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
     at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 8]
        at com.zixcloudfoundary.ui.security.AuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'userid': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
     at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 8]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3556) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2651) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:856) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:753) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4340) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4189) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3242) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at com.zixcloudfoundary.ui.security.AuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
```

What I am doing is, I am sending a login request with userid and the password and then reading values in authentication filter like this.

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),
                    UserLoginRequestModel.class);
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUserid(), creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

When I run this application in debug mode then I got to know that it's throwing the exception while mapping the value from the request to Object at this point.

```
UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),
                        UserLoginRequestModel.class);
```

Also, I am authentication the user using userid as a username and the implementation of findUserbyUsername().

```
@Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException 
        {
            UserEntity details = dataCallback.findByuserid(username);
            if (details == null)
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid Username or Password.");
            return new User(details.getUserId(), details.getEncryptedPassword(), true, true, 
            true, true, new ArrayList());
        }
```

Please help me guys, I am stuck here for long because of that I am unable to make progress in my project! Let me know if you need anything else related to project configuration.

Comment: can you share your code? I want to run in my IDEA

Comment: Of course, github link: https://github.com/MindFlayerA/Dynamo.git

One question, do you write blogs on baeldung?

Comment: lol, your repo is empty

Comment: I am uploading the code, I guess I gave you repo so early lol

Comment: what are you sending?

Comment: The github repo is updated now

Comment: Guys, any update?

Comment: I wanted to run your project by building it and then running from command line java -jar Dynamo.0.2.jar, but when I go to http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/users the controller does not map and I get 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @eugen you will have to request on localhost:8080/users/, you're missing out / after users

Comment: thanks, another mistake now: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

Comment: @eugen please try verifying the path given in properties file and verify the file location

Comment: @M.Deinum any updates ?

Comment: I am trying to follow the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100212/by-default-where-does-spring-boot-expect-views-to-be-stored but still no avail. Does it work from command line on your machine?

Comment: @eugen it's working for me

Comment: ok I am trying with linux now, will report once run

Comment: I am still doing it, and I noticed the userID field that does not exist in registration. I will get back with more details soon

Comment: sorry, it took me a while. It is working now. See my answer below.

Comment: It's because the userid has to be generated with a class

Comment: The console will log the generated userid

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the mapping from request to java class as you have mentioned:

```
UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),
                        UserLoginRequestModel.class);
```

Change it to:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
            parameterMap.forEach((key,value) -> { params.put(key, value[0]); });
String json = String.format( "{ \"userid\" : \"%s\", \"password\" : \"%s\" }", parameterMap.get("userid")[0], parameterMap.get("password")[0]);
UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, UserLoginRequestModel.class);
```

A little bit wordy but less magic and works :)

Comment: I'll check @eugen and I appreciate your help

Comment: I didn't check yet! I work for corporates so I was busy with secheduling to manage work from home. I'll test it by tomorrow itself and I wanted to ask if you would like to contribute with me in making this application? Cause I have a great idea and I was not able to find someone to help

Comment: sure, how can I get in touch with you?